# Providing null value for elasticsearch date field

Tags: c#, .net, class, elasticsearch, nest

I just wanted to know if anyone knows how to provide a null value for an elasticsearch date field.

You can see in the screenshot below that it is possible to utilise a DateTime for the null value but when I try it doesn't accept it. Producing the error message:

"'NullValue' is not a valid named attribute argument brecause it is not a valid attribute parameter type."

[Date field options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RddXp.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `NullValue` for `DateAttribute` is a `DateTime`, it can't be set on a attribute applied to a POCO property because the set value would need to be a compile time constant. This is one of the limitations of going with the attribute approach to mapping.

`NullValue` can be set in a couple of ways:

**Using the fluent API**

The fluent mapping can do everything that attribute mapping can do, as well as handle functionality such as null values, multi_fields, etc.

```cs
public class MyDocument
{
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}

var fluentMappingResponse = client.Map<MyDocument>(m => m
    .Index("index-name")
    .AutoMap()
    .Properties(p => p
        .Date(d => d
            .Name(n => n.DateOfBirth)
            .NullValue(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc))
        )
    )
);
```

**Using a visitor pattern**

Define a visitor that will visit all the properties in the POCO, and use this to set a null value. The visitor pattern is useful for applying conventions to your mapping, for example, all string properties should be a multi_field with a not analyzed raw sub field.

```cs
public class MyPropertyVisitor : NoopPropertyVisitor
{
    public override void Visit(IDateProperty type, PropertyInfo propertyInfo, ElasticsearchPropertyAttributeBase attribute)
    {
        if (propertyInfo.DeclaringType == typeof(MyDocument) &&
            propertyInfo.Name == nameof(MyDocument.DateOfBirth))
        {
            type.NullValue = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        }
    }
}

var visitorMappingResponse = client.Map<MyDocument>(m => m
    .Index("index-name")
    .AutoMap(new MyPropertyVisitor())
);
```

both the fluent mapping and visitor produce the following request

```
{
  "properties": {
    "dateOfBirth": {
      "null_value": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "type": "date"
    }
  }
}
```

[Take a look at the automapping documentation for more information.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/auto-map.html)

Comment: That's a great answer thank you! I was beginning to think it could be because of the approach I was using so that's why I went ahead and set the null value using the fluent API. Guess it's useful to keep that in mind for future reference.

Thank you for your help

Comment: @GSkidmore - no worries, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just used the following code instead of declaring it on the class date attribute:

```html
.Properties(pr => pr
  .Date(dt => dt
    .Name(n => n.dateOfBirth)
    .NullValue(new DateTime(0001, 01, 01))))
```